# how to create new object with computed function from knockout mapping

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

from .NET, I have `List<Item>` and I deserialized  it into JSON:

```
"Item":[{"p1":1,"p2":2,....},{"p1":1,,"p2":2,....}]
```

I added some custom computable functions for item object:

```
    var Moptions = {
                 'Item': {
                     create: function (options) {
                         return (new (function () {

                             this.calcDateAuto = ko.computed(function () {

                         return something;
    },this);
ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data, {}, this);
```

I was able to parse the data and custom computed functions from Knockout object:

```
var viewmodel = ko.mapping.fromJS(JSON,Moptions);
```

What I wanted to do is to allow user to add new Item(client side) to my knockout view model. I'm stuck at trying to use the right object(please note that I would like the computed functions with the object)

```
viewmodel.addItem = function () {
viewmodel.Item.push( /* what should I use here */)
}
```

I have found this post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18150539/adding-a-new-object-to-observable-array-in-knockout-mvc][1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18150539/adding-a-new-object-to-observable-array-in-knockout-mvc%5d%5b1%5d). But it's a little different for my situation because I have computed functions.

**EDIT**
A workaround for this would be able to create an empty object for Item. Is there a way to do this? I tried to do(doesn't work):

```
var temp = ko.toJSON(viewmodel.Item);
var newmodel = ko.mapping.fromJS(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the structure of Item currently? As long as you ensure the values are formatted the same, then you should be good to go. Just be sure that 'Items' is not just an array, but an observableArray...otherwise you'll be changing your object but no seeing it in your UI.

Comment: I have a list of Item objects. As I said, I was able to parse and get data for all my Item objects. I just wanted to know the proper syntax or method to add new Item to knockout object.

Comment: It seems like your understanding of the mapping function may be the culprit, but your example isn't detailed enough for me to know for sure. If you're still having problems, then you should make a fiddle or something to best replicate the problem at hand...then someone (such as myself), can help...it appears as though you're just using SO for the first time. Better answers require well formatted questions.

Comment: ok...we also have an issue with your understanding of a jsfiddle...you're referring to jQuery and not providing it. also, the reference to ko.mapping is another reference and NOT included in your base knockout framework...it must be provided

Comment: oh, and you really don't need to provide such a large dataset to get this all tested with...just makes for a headache

Answer (score 0):

So there are similar scenarios like mine on SO, but unfortunately in my case I manually added some computed functions to my Item object during mapping.

I ended up doing this in my Add Item function:

```
viewmodel.addItem = function () {
var options = {

                     create: function (options) {
                         return (new (function () {

                             this.calcDateAuto = ko.computed(function () {

                         return something;
    },this);
ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data, {}, this);
};
var item = serverModel.Item()[0];

            var newItem = ko.mapping.fromJS(ko.mapping.toJS(item),options);
            serverModel.Item.push(newItem);
}
```

What this basically does is to take one existing Item object in the observable array, deserialize it to JSON and use knockout mapping plugin to convert it back to an object. But the key here is the mapping options. This is similar to the "Moptions" except that it is not looking for "Item" object.